# How to format a complex object to another complex object?

Tags: javascript

I have a big problem to format my complex object into another complex object.
I get the first type of complex object from an incoming device Message. I cannot change the format of the incoming message.

I try to format my message into another complex object to use it somewhere else in my program.

Here is the format of the incoming message :

```
var measures = [
    {
        dev: "test",
        usg: "IMPORT",
        vals: [
            { val: 1000, date: "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"},
            { val: 2000, date: "2019-01-02T00:00:00Z"},
            { val: 3000, date: "2019-01-03T00:00:00Z"}
        ]
    },
    {
        dev: "test2",
        usg: "EXPORT",
        vals: [
            { val: 300, date: "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"},
            { val: 400, date: "2019-01-02T00:00:00Z"},
            { val: 500, date: "2019-01-03T00:00:00Z"}
        ]
    }
];
```

The dates are the same for the 2 measures that i get. That is perfectly normal and that is what i'm trying to use.

Now it is the expected format. Dates must be a dictionary where dates are the keys.

```
Dates = [ 
   { 
        "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z" : { 
             {usg : "IMPORT", dev : "test", val : 1000 },
             {usg : "EXPORT", dev : "test2" val : 300 } 
   },
   { 
        "2019-01-02T00:00:00Z" : { 
            { usg : "IMPORT", dev : "test", val : 2000},
            { usg : "EXPORT", dev : "test2", val : 400 }
   },
   { 
        "2019-01-03T00:00:00Z" : { 
            { usg : "IMPORT", dev : "test", val : 3000},
            { usg : "EXPORT", dev : "test2", val : 500 }
   }
];
```

I managed to get a dictionary like this :

```
Dates = [ 
   { 
        "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z" : { 
             { val : 1000 },
             { val : 300 } 
   },
   { 
        "2019-01-02T00:00:00Z" : { 
            { val : 2000},
            { val : 400 }
   },
   { 
        "2019-01-03T00:00:00Z" : { 
            { val : 3000},
            { val : 500 }
   }
];
```

with the following code but I cannot reach the "usg" and "dev" properties in the last part of the  .map method.

```
var dates = measures.map(varVals => varVals.vals)
.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))
.map(varDates => varDates.date);

var dicoVal = {};
dates.forEach(date => dicoVal[date] = 
    measures.map(varVals => varVals.vals)
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))
    .filter(item => item.date == date)
    .map(valeur => { val : valeur.val}));
```

I tried to get "varVals.usg" or "varVals.dev", but it's not reachable and I know why but I can't find a solution to this.

That's my problem.

Thanks for reading !

I hope you will enjoy solving my problem :D

Comment: this is not a valid JSON format: `"2019-01-01T00:00:00Z" : { 
             {usg : "IMPORT", dev : "test", val : 1000 },
             {usg : "EXPORT", dev : "test2" val : 300 }`
there is a missing `} ` and `"2019-01-01T00:00:00Z" : {` means object (key/value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the inner object is an array, you can use `reduce` to summarize the array into an object. Use `Object.values()` to convert the object into an array.

Use `forEach` to loop through the array.

```js
var measures = [{"dev":"test","usg":"IMPORT","vals":[{"val":1000,"date":"2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"},{"val":2000,"date":"2019-01-02T00:00:00Z"},{"val":3000,"date":"2019-01-03T00:00:00Z"}]},{"dev":"test2","usg":"EXPORT","vals":[{"val":300,"date":"2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"},{"val":400,"date":"2019-01-02T00:00:00Z"},{"val":500,"date":"2019-01-03T00:00:00Z"}]}];

var date = Object.values(measures.reduce((c, v) => {
  v.vals.forEach(o => {
    c[o.date] = c[o.date] || {[o.date]: []};
    c[o.date][o.date].push({usg: v.usg,dev: v.dev,val: o.val});
  })
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(date);
```

Comment: Hello @Eddie.
I figured out that i need a more detailed object.
It must be like this
```javascript
Measures = [ 
   { 
       date :  "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
       usages : [ 
             {usg : "IMPORT", dev : "test", val : 1000 },
             {usg : "EXPORT", dev : "test2" val : 300 } 
       ]
   },
   {
     date : "2019-01-02T00:00:00Z", etc etc....

   }
]
```
How can I do that with your example ?

Comment: That's alright !
I finally found the way to do it :)
`var Measures= Object.values(measures.reduce((c, v) => {
        v.vals.forEach(o => {
          c[o.date] = c[o.date] || {date : o.date, usages: []};
          c[o.date].usages.push({usg: v.usg,dev: v.dev,val: o.val});
        })
        return c;
      }, {}));`